# Latex indentation with enumitem package

Tags: latex, indentation

I read the documentation in this pdf http://www.texnia.com/archive/enumitem.pdf. I couldn't figure out how to get the text to be flush with the edge. Ideally the bullets would be one indent to the left (if that makes any sense).

This is how it looks for me:
[image: picture of output pdf]

This is the code to reproduce:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist{nosep} % makes spacing around lists normal
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} % no indent for paragraphs

\newcommand{\area}[2]{
\vspace{0.5mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.15\textwidth}
{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\
\bfseries\uppercase {#1}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}
{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

{#2}}
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\area{testing}{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur suscipit
lorem in augue posuere efficitur. Aenean non eros varius, condimentum nulla eu,
viverra ligula. Nunc at pellentesque enim. Sed blandit facilisis tortor, a
suscipit libero hendrerit eu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et
netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent auctor egestas tincidunt.
Curabitur eu cursus turpis. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin dolor, gravida
condimentum massa. Aliquam in velit augue. Fusce eget elit lobortis, eleifend
magna ac, convallis elit. Integer ut eleifend orci. Maecenas et urna vel metus
rhoncus tincidunt. Etiam at sapien vitae tellus interdum viverra vel sed mi.
Suspendisse a neque vestibulum, rhoncus massa vitae, dictum leo.
}

\area{testing2}{
\begin{itemize}[left= -\parindent .. 0pt]
\item
Curabitur eu cursus turpis. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin dolor, gravida
condimentum massa. Aliquam in velit augue. Fusce eget elit lobortis, eleifend
magna ac, convallis elit. Integer ut eleifend orci. Maecenas et urna vel metus
rhoncus tincidunt. Etiam at sapien vitae tellus interdum viverra vel sed mi.
\item
Curabitur eu cursus turpis. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin dolor, gravida
condimentum massa. Aliquam in velit augue. Fusce eget elit lobortis, eleifend
magna ac, convallis elit. Integer ut eleifend orci. Maecenas et urna vel metus
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Anything will help thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to modify the `leftmargin`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist{nosep} % makes spacing around lists normal
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} % no indent for paragraphs

\newcommand{\area}[2]{
\vspace{0.5mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.15\textwidth}
{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\
\bfseries\uppercase {#1}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}
{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

{#2}}
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\area{testing}{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur suscipit
lorem in augue posuere efficitur. Aenean non eros varius, condimentum nulla eu,
viverra ligula. Nunc at pellentesque enim. Sed blandit facilisis tortor, a
suscipit libero hendrerit eu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et
netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent auctor egestas tincidunt.
Curabitur eu cursus turpis. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin dolor, gravida
condimentum massa. Aliquam in velit augue. Fusce eget elit lobortis, eleifend
magna ac, convallis elit. Integer ut eleifend orci. Maecenas et urna vel metus
rhoncus tincidunt. Etiam at sapien vitae tellus interdum viverra vel sed mi.
Suspendisse a neque vestibulum, rhoncus massa vitae, dictum leo.
}

\area{testing2}{
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0cm]
\item
Curabitur eu cursus turpis. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin dolor, gravida
condimentum massa. Aliquam in velit augue. Fusce eget elit lobortis, eleifend
magna ac, convallis elit. Integer ut eleifend orci. Maecenas et urna vel metus
rhoncus tincidunt. Etiam at sapien vitae tellus interdum viverra vel sed mi.
\item
Curabitur eu cursus turpis. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin dolor, gravida
condimentum massa. Aliquam in velit augue. Fusce eget elit lobortis, eleifend
magna ac, convallis elit. Integer ut eleifend orci. Maecenas et urna vel metus
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]